# Is the eigenspace of a matrix $A$ equal to the diminution of the null space of $A-LI$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im aware that the geometric multiplicity of A is equal to the dimention of the eiegenspace of A (spanned by its eigenvectors for each eigenvalue).

But the dimention of the eigenspace of A is also equal to the dimention of the null space of A-LI (or the nullrank of A-LI) where L is some eiegenvalue of the matrix A right?

I want to ask if this is correct because ive seen somewhere that the geometeic multiplicity of a matrix A is n-(the rank of A-LI) where n is the dimention of A but i thought the geometric multiplicity is equal to dimention of the null space of A-LI so in other words the rank of A-LI

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: @GiulioR also does rank and nullrank mean the same thing? So is the rank of A-LI equat to the nullrank of A-LI?

Comment: By definition, rank a linear transformation $B$ = dimension of the image of $B$.
The rank-nullity theorem says that the rank of $B$ + dimension of kernel of $B$ is the dimension of the full space. Apply this theorem to your case: $B=A-\lambda I$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, dimension of the full space $= n$. Hence $n-rank(A-\lambda I)=\dim \ker(A-\lambda I)$. Never heard about anything called "nullrank".

Comment: Matrix doesn't have a multiplicity, at least in this context. Also, it is **dimension**, not `dimention`. $\color{red}{(=:}$ Nobody is perfect, but some typos distract readers. Make sure you **read** your posts before posting in future.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then  $$\text{The eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ is defined to be null$(A-\lambda I)$}$$
$$\text{Geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=\dim$ null $(A-\lambda I)$}$$

Comment: Ok thanks im studying  A-levels so sorry for my lack of knowledge on this basic stuff since im just using random resources and not an actual book or a course

Comment: @Mahfuz There is no need to apologise. Everyone gets confused with definitions from time to time!